# php variable in a echo string

Tags: php, wordpress, var

I'm customizing a wordpress for the first time so I'm pretty new with PHP langage and something is driving me crazy.
I wrote that function to transform my HTML5/CSS3/JQUERY layout into a CMS:

```
<?php $property = simple_fields_values("pillow_front");
  foreach ($property as $value) {
    echo "<div class='solo'>";
      echo "<div class='box coussin'>";
        echo "<div class='outImg'><img src='" . wp_get_attachment_url($value) . "'/></div>";
      echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
  }
?>
```

But in the front-end it doesn't work and when I look at the code it appears that the img tag is not closed properly:

```
<div class="solo">
  <div class="box coussin" style="width: 328px; height: 328px;">
    <div class="outImg" style="opacity: 1;">
      <img src="http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/021.jpg" style="width: 328px; height: 328px;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I didn't really well understoud if the . in PHP was the exact equivalent of the + in javascript but I tried a lots of thing and I can get that tag to be properly closed !

Thank you

Comment: Are you looking at the page source or something like the Elements view in Chrome's Developer Tools?

Comment: how is that style being added? also something is not right, that cant be the output because the single quotes magically change to double quotes

Comment: Could you paste the exact code from the page source of the brower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or just a bit more MVC-Pattern or in that case just MV? ;) Try this one without Wordpress.

```
<?php

    //Init
    $property = simple_fields_values("pillow_front");
    $template = '<div class="solo">
       <div class="box coussin">
        <div class="outImg"><img src="{MARKER:FRONT}" /></div>
       </div>
      </div>';

    foreach ($property as $value) {
        echo str_replace(array('{MARKER:FRONT}'), array($value), $template);
    }
?>
```

And as i know wordpress view, your code style is not confirm to WP-Styleguide. WP is using HTML/PHP Templating. In WP you view need to look like this.

```
<?php foreach(simple_fields_values("pillow_front") as $value): ?>
<div class='solo'>
    <div class='box coussin'>
        <div class='outImg'><img src="<?php echo htmlentities(value): ?>"/></div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Actually the issue was somewhere else in my code, a conflict between things formatted by php and other by jquery... But the "less php you can do" really helped me so thank you for the tips. And it seems with HTML5, img tags doesn't need to be closed anymore...

Answer (score 0):

You can print in another system, something like this:

```
<?php 
$property = simple_fields_values("pillow_front");
 foreach ($property as $value) {
 ?>
  <div class='solo'>
   <div class='box coussin'>
    <div class='outImg'><img src="<?php print wp_get_attachment_url($value);?>"/></div>
   </div>
  </div>
 <?php
 }
 ?>
```

Please note that i put the echo of the function only because i do not know how it works, it can be not necessary, use php only when needed.